# Github Pages and Jekyll permalinks going to different paths

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, permalinks

I have a site running locally with Jekyll and deployed to GitHub Pages without any issues.

The issue I have is with GitHub pages and local permalinks.

```
https://username.github.io/my-repositary
```

and localhost is going to the root

```
http://localhost:4000/
```

So adding a page About in the root and linking to ends up looking like this

```
https://username.github.io/about
http://localhost:4000/about
```

Rather than the desired outcome

```
https://username.github.io/my-repositary/about
http://localhost:4000/about
```

Comment: Have you added `baseurl: my-repositary` to your `_config.yml` file?

Comment: Thats what I was missing! Thank you! :)

Comment: I'll put the answer then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jekyll allows you to specify a subpath for the page you are generating via the `baseurl` option in the `_config.yml` file. In this case, yours should add this line to it:

```yaml
baseurl: /my-repositary
```